# Ora 01403 when try to insert data into oracle table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following trigger

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER L_BIUR_G_LAY
         BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON G_LAY
         FOR EACH ROW
        When (new.g_roo is not null)
          DECLARE
          x number(1);
         stmt varchar(255);
           BEGIN
          FOR I IN (SELECT DISTINCT G_TAB FROM G_LEG)
          LOOP

               stmt := 'select distinct g_lind from ' || i.g_tab || ' where g_roo = ' || :new.g_roo;
          Execute immediate stmt into x;

        IF (x<>0)  THEN 
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-2001, 'G_ROO  cannot be inserted where G_LIND IS NOT ZERO');
         END IF;
           END LOOP;
    END;
 /
```

and when I do

```
   insert into G_LAY (G_OGCS, G_OGC, G_ROO, G_NM, G_TI,   G_AB, G_DATE)
        (select G_LAY_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 1, G_ROO, G_LGNDIT, G_UNE, 'Pipe  Data Long - ' || G_UR, sysdate
             from G_DTABLE where G_LIND = 0);
```

I get the following error
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "L_BIUR_G_LAY", line 10
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'G_LAY'
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It tried PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION after Declare in my trigger but it didn't help me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your INSERT statement. The problem occurs when the dynamically-built SELECT statement in the trigger is executed - no data is found so an ORA-01403 is raised. It looks to me like the easiest thing to do would be to do a SELECT COUNT(...):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER L_BIUR_G_LAY
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON G_LAY
  FOR EACH ROW
  When (new.g_rowno is not null)
DECLARE
  x number;
  stmt varchar(255);
BEGIN
  FOR I IN (SELECT DISTINCT G_DISPCNTRLTAB FROM G_LEG) LOOP
    stmt := 'select COUNT(*) from ' || i.g_dispcntrltab ||
            ' where g_rowno = ' || :new.g_rowno ||
              ' and g_lind <> 0';

    Execute immediate stmt into x;

    IF x <> 0 THEN 
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'G_RWNO  cannot be inserted where G_LIND IS NOT ZERO');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END L_BIUR_G_LAY;
```

I also changed the error number which is raised as -2001 is not in the range of errors which can be raised using RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (the valid range is -20000 to -20999).

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Being new to the world of plsql I thought that it's a valid exception since I'm not handling the no data found before an insert or update but then I changed my code (not Bob's) and made it After insert even then I got the same problem and I was astonished to see the same error message.However I was under an impression that if I change my trigger from before insert to after insert no data found error will go , since the after insert trigger will run after the insertion happened but before the data could be visible in the G_LAY table but to my surprise it didn't happen. Don't know why.